# PyYaml fails to load YAML from string when one of the object is nested class

Tags: python, yaml

First, let me introduce a simple example that works.

```py
import yaml


class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nc1 = 11
        self.nc2 = 22


class WorkingParent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = 11
        self.p2 = 22
        self.nc = Child()


parent = WorkingParent()
yaml_parent_str = yaml.dump(parent)

print("**** yaml_parent_str ***")
print(yaml_parent_str)

print("**** parent_from_yaml_str ***")
parent_from_yaml_str = yaml.load(yaml_parent_str)
print(parent_from_yaml_str)
```

This console output is as below which is correct. YAML is able to create an object from str `yaml_parent_str`

```
**** yaml_parent_str ***
!!python/object:__main__.WorkingParent
nc: !!python/object:__main__.Child {nc1: 11, nc2: 22}
p1: 11
p2: 22

**** parent_from_yaml_str ***
<__main__.WorkingParent object at 0x000001A5BF200470>
```

Now let us see what does not work

```py
import yaml


class NotWorkingParent:
    class NestedChild:
        def __init__(self):
            self.nc1 = 11
            self.nc2 = 22

    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = 11
        self.p2 = 22
        self.nc = NotWorkingParent.NestedChild()


parent = NotWorkingParent()
yaml_parent_str = yaml.dump(parent)

print("**** yaml_parent_str ***")
print(yaml_parent_str)

print("**** parent_from_yaml_str ***")
parent_from_yaml_str = yaml.load(yaml_parent_str)
print(parent_from_yaml_str)
```

This results in as below. You can see that YAML is not able to create an object from str `yaml_parent_str`.

```
**** yaml_parent_str ***
!!python/object:__main__.NotWorkingParent
nc: !!python/object:__main__.NestedChild {nc1: 11, nc2: 22}
p1: 11
p2: 22

**** parent_from_yaml_str ***
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object
cannot find 'NestedChild' in the module '__main__'
  in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 5:
    nc: !!python/object:__main__.NestedC ... 
        ^
```

You can see that the problem is YAML lib thinks that `NestedClass` is

```
nc: !!python/object:__main__.NestedChild {nc1: 11, nc2: 22}
```

instead of

```
nc: !!python/object:__main__.NotWorkingParent.NestedChild {nc1: 11, nc2: 22}
```

How can this be solved ???

Answer (score 1):

Tell PyYAML the tag it should use for the classes:

```
import yaml

class Parent(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!Parent'
    yaml_loader = yaml.SafeLoader
    class NestedChild(yaml.YAMLObject):
        yaml_tag = u'!Child'
        yaml_loader = yaml.SafeLoader
        def __init__(self):
            self.nc1 = 11
            self.nc2 = 22

    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = 11
        self.p2 = 22
        self.nc = Parent.NestedChild()

parent = Parent()
yaml_parent_str = yaml.dump(parent)

print("**** yaml_parent_str ***")
print(yaml_parent_str)

print("**** parent_from_yaml_str ***")
parent_from_yaml_str = yaml.safe_load(yaml_parent_str)
print(parent_from_yaml_str)
```

By deriving from `yaml.YAMLObject`, you can specify the tag with `yaml_tag`. Note that I also set `yaml_loader` so that you can use `yaml.safe_load` instead of `yaml.load`, which should always be done because `yaml.load` is a security problem since a user can cause the code to instantiate arbitrary classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I do not want to subclass `yaml.YAMLObject` ... can you suggest how can that be done?

Comment: You can also use `yaml.add_representer` and `yaml.add_constructor` with custom tags, but then you need to implement loading and dumping the objects yourself. I advice to subclass `yaml.YAMLObject` instead; „I do not want to do that“ is not a good comeback to a possible solution.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that too but then I cannot support subclassed classes for YAML serialization... I need to go and make every subclass compatible... instead I overrided __getstate__ to support subclasses .... So basically I am not fond of `yaml.add_constructor` and `yaml.add_representer` but instead, I think I need to make a fake reference in __main__ module like `NestedChild=Parent.NestedChild`